# Customizing the Spring parameter parser

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am looking to add a some strict cross-scripting rules to my application which is based on Spring. I added the recommended html 'defaultHtmlEscape' to true and used the  tag, but there are still some things we would like to prevent. I decided to use the java html sanitizer from https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project . This will require me to call the sanitizing function every where a parameter is read, which is changes in a lot of places. Is there a central place I can do this? Perhaps, a class through which all the parameters are parsed? I saw that the NamedParameterUtils is used internally in Spring to parse the parameters. Is there a way to extend it?

Is there any other way of doing this in Spring framework?

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

thanks,

Asha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question. You can add a filter class in Spring and have the parameters pass through them. More information is at: http://jeevanpatil.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/prevention_of_xss/ in the 'Filter Approach' section.